# ngrx store reducer configuration (angular 5)

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am using ngrx/store in my Angular 5 project.
The Application state I store has multiple properties (slices).
I want to individually be able to listen to changes to any of those properties.
So in this case, should I be using multiple reducers - one for each state slice?
Can it be achieved with one reducer?
I am guessing it cannot be done, because with one reducer we will return a new copy of the entire state, rather than a slice.
For e.g.

```
class AppState{
    private customerList: Customer [];
    private selectedCustomer: Customer;
    private countriesOperational: Country [];
}
```

I want to be able to listen to changes only on selectedCustomer, so I can do this:

```
store.select(state => state.selectedCustomer).subscribe((data) => {
})
```

Comment: sounds u mistake reducers and selectors?

Comment: What i mean is, currently I have one reducer registered in my module as
StoreModule.forRoot({appState: customerReducer});

This reducer returns a copy of the entire AppState every time there is an action. Hence i am unable to do 
store.select(state => state.selectedCustomer). It always returns undefined, since I am returning an entirely new AppState object. Hence i was wondering if I should have individual reducers for each individual slice, that return only a new copy of that slice.

Answer (score 1):

First of all - there is no need to have several reducers. The new reducer should be implemented once you feel that your current reducer is too big / has multiple resposibilities / should be splitted due to some constrains.

Going back to your problem -  lets say that your customer has 'id' property. And in the scenario that I want to present, the app will be showing list of current ids - from customerList. The customerList is going to be dynamically updated using ngrx actions (and the template will be listening to the changes).

In component:

```
public customerIds$: Observable<string[]>;

public ngOnInit(): void {
   this customerIds$ = this.store.select(
      state => state.customersList.map(customer => customer.id);
   );
}
```

In your template:

```
<div *ngFor="let id of customerIds$ | async">
   {{id}}
</div>
```

Right now (using async pipe) you connected your html template with ts component. So, lets say that you have a button that is adding a new customer to customersList:

```
<button (click)="addNewCustomer()">Add new customer</button>
```

And the `addNewCustomer()` method is dispatching an action, that is handled by your store. The result of an action is hiddin in reducer, sth like that:

```
... (reducer logic)
   case ADD_NEW_CUSTOMER:
      return {
        ...state,
        customersList: [...state.customersLits, action.payload]
```

Where:

- action.payload - is the new customer that you want to add
- [...state.customersList ...... ] syntax - the array needs to be updated using immutable approach - more can be found here: https://vincent.billey.me/pure-javascript-immutable-array/

Once the button is clicked, new customer id is displayed in the template

Comment: But the problem is you are still returning a full AppState object from the reducer. So if i do a store.select(state => state.customersList).subscribe(data=>{});, it returns undefined for data.

Comment: Could you share you project via github (or any provider)? For sure there is some thing that I'm missing in you configuration.

Comment: You could check here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52469627/ngrx-store-reducer-wrapping-return-value-in-object - Unfortunately, i am unable to share the code via GitHub.